# Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:"

Tags: node.js, vue.js, mongoose, content-security-policy, cloudinary

after i uploaded my website on herokuy the images do not working and it gave me that error

Refused to load the image '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".

i have tried somethings like

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; font-src data:" />`

that but it does not work also

Comment: Https://res.clodinary.com/image/upload/''imagenamehere".jpg

Comment: The website like https://facebook-clones.herokuapp.com/

Comment: `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' clodinary.com *.clodinary.com`

Comment: Btw, you have a typo there - it's cloudinary and not clodinary.

Comment: that is the error >>>>  Refused to load the image 'https://res.cloudinary.com/ammarleejot/image/upload/v1609954985/j7v7ezyvnax9fuokrryb.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".

Comment: and i tried that >>>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
   img-src * 'self' https://res.cloudinary.com data: https://res.cloudinary.com:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
   style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Comment: Looks like you have a CSP header is issued by Helmet middleware. When you publishes CSP via HTTP header, you can't relax it using meta tag.

Comment: as you said it was wrong with halmet and i did it

Comment: yeap the probelm was with helmet in node js as @granty said here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66421706/refused-to-load-the-image-https-res-cloudinary-com-violngecurity-policy-di/66421905#66421905

Answer (score 5):

```
app.use(helmet({ crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false, originAgentCluster: true }));
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: {
      "img-src": ["'self'", "https: data: blob:"],
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Better practice instead of setting contentSecurityPolicy to false which should be the most last option. Using the [Helmet documentation](https://helmetjs.github.io) helps alot. I used this in [my app](https://github.com/kimanicharles911/movimusify_react_and_express_fullstack/blob/master/app.js) and it solves the issue very well. My app is hosted [here](https://movimusifyreactexpressmern.herokuapp.com). Checkout my source code [here](https://github.com/kimanicharles911/movimusify_react_and_express_fullstack/blob/master/app.js).

```
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: {
      "img-src": ["'self'", "https: data:"]
    }
  })
)
```

Comment: for me "https: data: blob:" was needed on heroku. this did not work

Answer (score 2):

This disables the `contentSecurityPolicy` middleware but keeps the rest:

```js
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: false,
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue

```
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginEmbedderPolicy({ policy: "credentialless" }));
app.use(
    helmet({
        crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
        originAgentCluster: true
    })
);
app.use(
    helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
            "img-src": ["'self'", "https:", "data:", "blob:"]
        }
    })
);
```