# Refused to load the image 'https://res.cloudinary.com/.. violngecurity Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:"

Tags: html, node.js, vue.js, meta-tags, content-security-policy

iam using vue.js and node.js and i upload photos in cloudinary and when i upload the website on heroku it work well but get me an error for images and i tried a lot of  ways to solve but it does not work
that is the error

```
Refused to load the image 'https://res.cloudinary.com/ammarleejot/image/upload/v1609954985/j7v7ezyvnax9fuokrryb.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
```

and that is my meta tag that i have tried to use

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src *  data: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-dynamic'; script-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src * data: blob: ; style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';

```
and when i check my website on https://csper.io/evaluations/603cd4e5b55c2090fdd9fb4a
it show me that result 

default-src 'self'
base-uri 'self'
block-all-mixed-content
font-src 'self' data: https:
frame-ancestors 'self'
img-src 'self' data:
object-src 'none'
script-src 'self'
script-src-attr 'none'
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https:
upgrade-insecure-requests
```

Answer (score 2):

You have CSP published in HTTP header, probably via [Helmet](https://helmetjs.github.io/#reference) middleware.
Disable it in `helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(options)` if you wish to use `<meta Content Security Policy>` tag.
Or configure CSP header in Helmet.

In case of two Content Security Policy at the same time more strict will aply.

BTW:

- `'unsafe-dynamic'` is incorrect token
- `'unsafe-inline'` token is not supported in `connect-src`/`img-src`/`font-src` directives.

Comment: thank you soooooooooooooooo much i did it the wrong was with helmt as you said and i edited it like that app.use(hamlet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: false,
})) and it worked now

Comment: yeap sure could you tell me how  to vote because i do not know it

Comment: @AjeetShah thank you for that i really appreciate that to you i do not have experience in using it so i still learning

Answer (score 1):

I saw in the comment that you have solved by setting **contentSecurityPolicy** to false, in this way you are disabling CSP, I don't think that it is what you were looking for...

If you want to give access to that specific domain you should add it to your helmet directive under img-src just like this

```
helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
        directives: {
            "default-src":[ "'self'" ],
            "base-uri":[ "'self'" ],
            "font-src":[ "'self'", "https:", "data:" ],
            "frame-ancestors":[ "'self'" ],
            "img-src":[ "'self'", "data:", "http://res.cloudinary.com"], <--- HERE
            "script-src":[ "'self'" ],
            "script-src-attr":[ "'none'" ],
            "style-src":[ "'self'", "https:", "'unsafe-inline'" ],
        }
    });
```

And here you can add or remove depending on what you want to allow.

It depend on your application but usally is better to enable CSP to prevent a good amount of attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to upload blob in cloudinary but with helmet it wasn't allowing due to cross origin policy. While in local it wasn't causing any issue, in Production the images are not showing up. Doing app.use(helmet({ crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false}) allows it to upload.

```
app.use(helmet({ crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false, originAgentCluster: true }));
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: {
      "img-src": ["'self'", "https: data: blob:"],
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Was having same issue, but now its loading image from cloudinary

```
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: {
      "img-src": ["https://mysitename.com", "https://res.cloudinary.com/"],
      upgradeInsecureRequests: [],
    },
    reportOnly: false,
  })
);
```